# How can I use an IF statement within a view to display a table depending on the result received?

Tags: html, vb.net, model-view-controller

At the moment I have created two tables within my view, each table is different. One contains a summary of information and the other a detailed view. I have passed a variable in called 'Report Type'. If it is type 1, I would like it to display the summary table. If it is type 2, I would like it to display the detailed table. My question is, how would I go about doing this? My code is below, you can see both tables and also how the Report Type will be passed in. Thank you.

```
 <% Using Html.BeginForm("ReportCriteria", "Reports", Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "formReportCriteria"})%>

    <center>

    <%: MasterPageHelpers.ContainerStart("wid1", "Results", 16)%>

    <div>
        Date From: <%: Model.DateFrom%>
        <br />
        Date To: <%: Model.DateTo%>
        <br />
        Report Type: <%: Model.ReportType%>
    </div>
        <div>
        <table class="sorted-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Client</th>
                    <th>Tickets Created</th>
                    <th>Tickets Resolved</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <%
                   Dim oResult As Object
                   For Each oResult In Model.ReportResults
                       Response.Write("<tr>")
                       Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ClientName & "</td>")
                       Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.CreatedCount & "</td>")
                       Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ResolvedCount & "</td>")
                       Response.Write("</tr>")
                   Next


                %>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table class="sorted-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Classification</th>
                        <th>Tickets Created</th>
                        <th>Tickets Resolved</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <% 
                    For Each oResult In Model.ReportResults
                        Response.Write("<tr")
                        Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ClientName & "</td>")
                        Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ClassificationDesc & "</td>")
                        Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.CreatedCount & "</td>")
                        Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ResolvedCount & "</td>")
                    Next
                %>
                </tbody>
             </table> 
         </div>
    </center>

    <% End Using%>


    <%: MasterPageHelpers.ContainerEnd%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something along the following lines

```
@Code
   If Model.ReportType == 1 Then
      @<table>
  Else
      @<table>
  End If
End Code
```

[See this post](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(vb)#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode)

**Update - code for aspx as per your comments**

```
  <% If Model.ReportType == 1 Then %>
      <table> ... 
  <% Else %>
      <table> ...
  <% End If %>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. I already have called in my Model which allows me to use my passed in variables. I am using ASP. Sorry for not specifying that. What does this part mean? '@<table>'. Sorry, I am new to this and find it difficult.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my earlier post as I noticed you had already passed the ReportType in as part of the model. Are you not using asp.net-mvc?  If so the syntax for your views will be razor.  The `@<table>` is just showing you where to put the table. you need to put the @ before if you are combining html in code.  If you read through the article I have linked to it gives some good examples of the syntax you need to use in your views

Comment: Thanks for replying Pete, I am using ASPX, not Razor. Thanks for clearing it up. I'll take a look now thanks

Comment: Ah ok that link is for Razor, for aspx it is a bit simpler - you just need to do your if statement in a code block and then close the code block, I have edit my above

Comment: Thank you! It works, you have been a great help and very kind by keeping your answer updated. I've learnt something new today. The problem was that I did not realise that at the end of every statement there must me the %>. I thought that I could have one at the start of the IF and one at the End.

Comment: Ah, yeah you need to break out of the vb code block to start doing the html again - unless you do a vb way of writing the html (something like a response.write)